# I have this error in Android Studio: Cannot change attributes of dependency configuration ':android:annotationProcessor' after it has been resolved

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

When i try to sync my Project with gradle files it gives me this error: Cannot change attributes of dependency configuration ':android:annotationProcessor' after it has been resolved. When i click on open file it goes to build.gradle in this method (see screenshot).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbc0l.png)